# Google Admob in windowd phone 8 using cocos2dx

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, admob, cocos2d-x

I have create a game in `cocos2dx` and integrate google admob for iOS and Android. 
now I want to integrate `google admob` in this `cocos2dx` game for Windows Phone 8.

How I can do this?

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Were you able to integrate the interstitial ads in cocos2d-x app for windows phone 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your game needs to be built from the WP8-xaml template rather than wp8.

Do you want banner ads or interstitial? For banner ads, once you've created a template it's straight forward, just follow the instructions on the admob site once you've got your WP8-XAML template app up and running.

Comment: What about interstitial ads ? how can we call showAd from cocos2d-x code?